# Find the word in large file and copy the line which contains that word

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, perl, sh

I am having two file i.e File_A and File_B. File_A contains single word on each line and File_B contains sentences. I have to read the word from File_A and search the line in File_B which start with that word and copy whole line to File_C. File_A and File_B both are sorted

For Example

**File_A :**

```
he
I
there
```

**File_B :**

```
he was at least equally intrigued by hers.
I guess he's going to use it in his business.
I don't know if he's angry or not.
there were five dogs.
there is fly in my soup.
we don't know what he is doing.
```

**File_C:**

```
he was at least equally intrigued by hers.
I guess he's going to use it in his business.
I don't know if he's angry or not.
there were five dogs.
there is fly in my soup.
```

I tried with shell script but it is heuristic method so it is taking long time. File_A and File_B both are large file.

Here is the code that I tried

```
#! /bin/bash

for first in `cat File_A`
do
    while read line 
    do
        first_col=$(echo $line|head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}')
        if [[ "$first" == "$first_col" ]]
        then
                 echo $line >> File_C
            fi  

    done <File_B
done
```

Comment: If you have specific issues while solving this yourself you can ask here. You should also decide first which programming language you want to use.

Comment: Please show your effort: include the code into the question, even if it does not work.

Comment: @MichaelButscher I already tagged programming language.

Comment: @DYZ  Here is the code that I have did #! /bin/bash

for first in `cat File_A`
do
 while read line 
 do
     first_col=$(echo $line|head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}')
     if [[ "$first" == "$first_col" ]]
     then
                 echo $line >> File_C
            fi 

 done <File_B
done

Comment: Please make it a part of the question. Do you expect us to read unformatted shell script in a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a shell that understands `<()` command redirection (Like `bash` or `zsh` but not posix `sh`) using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -wf <(sed 's/^/^/' file_a) file_b > file_c
```

`-f filename` reads the list of patterns/words from the given file, which in this case is the output of `sed 's/^/^/' file_a`, which puts a `^` start-of-line anchor at the start of each line (If your `file_a` includes characters that are special in regular expressions, this won't work right), and `-w` matches only whole words, to avoid cases where one of your words is a prefix of the first word in a line.

Comment: "_search the line in File_B which **start** with that word_"

Comment: @DYZ Doh. Fixed.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks for Answer. But its doing some mistake. It must be exact match of word. For example. File_A contains word "that" then it brings all sentences of "that", "that'll", "that's". I am expecting bring only "that".

Comment: @Amoll apostrophe counts as a word break. You'd have to add a check for a trailing space to the regular expressions created from the source words instead of using `-w` -- and edge cases like that should be included in your sample data.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the following code which was created based on you shell script.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $file_a = 'File_A';
my $file_b = 'File_B';
my $file_c = 'File_C';

# read File_A into array @data_a
open my $fh_a, '<', $file_a
    or die "Couldn't open $file_a $!";

my @data_a = <$fh_a>;

close $fh_a;

# read File_B into array @data_b
open my $fh_b, '<', $file_b
    or die "Couldn't open $file_b $!";

my @data_b = <$fh_b>;

close $fh_b;

chomp @data_a;      # snip eol
chomp @data_b;      # snip eol

# store found result into File_C
open my $fh_c, '>', $file_c
    or die "Couldn't open $file_b $!";

for my $word_a (@data_a) {
    for my $line_b (@data_b) {
        say $fh_c $line_b if $line_b =~ /^$word_a\b/;
    }
}

close $fh_c;
```

Input File_A

```
he
I
there
```

Input File_B

```
he was at least equally intrigued by hers.
I guess he's going to use it in his business.
I don't know if he's angry or not.
there were five dogs.
there is fly in my soup.
we don't know what he is doing.
```

Result File_C

```
he was at least equally intrigued by hers.
I guess he's going to use it in his business.
I don't know if he's angry or not.
we don't know what he is doing.
I guess he's going to use it in his business.
I don't know if he's angry or not.
there were five dogs.
there is fly in my soup.
```

Comment: `we don't know what he is doing.` This line shouldn't be in output as per the OP

Comment: You have `/\b$word_a\b/` where you need `/^$word_a\b/`. The question says "line in File_B which start with that word".

Comment: @Dave Cross -- sorry, I missed word 'start' in OP's post (corrected)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# Open File_A
open my $fh_a, '<', 'File_A' or die $!;

# Read words from File_A and remove newlines
chomp(my @words = <$fh_a>);

# Create a regex matching the words from File_A
# at the start of a line
my $word_re = '^(' . join('|', @words) . ')\b';
$word_re = qr($word_re);

# Open files B and C
open my $fh_b, '<', 'File_B' or die $!;
open my $fh_c, '>', 'File_C' or die $!;

# Read File_B a line at a time and write to
# File_C any lines that match our regex.
while (<$fh_b>) {
  print $fh_c $_ if /$word_re/;
}
```